# weird operator precedence and assignment behavior in borland turboC++

Tags: operators, turbo-c++, turbo-c, associativity

I have to use `borland TurboC++` for **C programming** in my college.
*They say our examination board recommends it. I **have** to use it.*.

The problem is that they gave this operator precedence related question:

```
int a=10,b=20,result;
result1 = ++a + b-- - a++ * b++ + a * ++b;
printf("result=%d",);
printf("\n a=%d",a);
printf("\n b=%d",b);
```

Other compilers like `gcc` can't perform this operation. But `turbo C` can and gives us:

`result=32
a=12
b=21`

I made mistake in my test. My teacher tried to explain what's going on. But I am not convinced. Is it some kind of weird behavior of `turbo C` or in older days it used to be totally fine with all compilers. If so, what are the steps to understand what is going on and how to understand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve these kind of problem, turbo-c do it in manner as follows :

1) Consider the initial value of variables used.

```
a=10
b=20
```

2) Count all the pre-increment and decrements for each variable and store all post on stack separate for each variable.

for variable `a`

```
pre increment = 1 therefore change the value of a to 11
post = 1 stored to stack
```

for variable `b`

```
pre increment = 1 therefore change the value of b to 21
post = 2 stored to stack
```

3) Now replace all the pre and post with the current value of a and b

```
result = 11 + 21 - 11 * 21 + 11 * 21 ;
result = 11 + 21;
result = 32;
```

4) lastly pop the stack and perform the operation on the variable.

```
a = 12
b = 21
```

This the only way to solve this problem. You can check the procedure with any question of same kind. The result will came out same. g++ fails to solve because it probably cannot resolve the variable in the same way thus the precedence error came in picture. It might probably fail with ++ + and -- - because it cannot understand the increment or decrements operator and forms ambiguous trees.

Comment: Thanks Ravinder. That helps a lot. Putting it in stack and popping it kind of gives a visual feedback to the problem.

Comment: someone edited my post. post operations that are stored on the stack will only be solved when the whole expression has been computed but the person who edited my post update it before that. This will produce an error when stack space is less consider a stack with 5 space and six posts operation alternative ++ and -- this case stack will only have 5 operations and according to my changed post, it can be solved.